# Flapdoodle fails with "authorization failed" error with Spring Boot v2.3.3

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, unit-testing, in-memory-database

We are upgrading our Spring Boot applications from from 2.2.5/7 to 2.3.3 and seeing unit test failure with Flapdoodle embedded MongoDb with error message `request fails with authentication failure message`

Can some please suggest any solution/workaround to the problems

The Spring Boot application has the following:

```
spring boot : 2.3.3
spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb : 2.3.3
mongodb-driver-core : 4.0.5
mongodb-driver-sync : 4.0.5
de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo - 2.2.0
de.flapdoodle.embed.process - 2.1.2
```

We have application repositories which are doing simple CRUD operations.

Test Class definition.

```
_@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataMongoTest
@activeprofiles({ "unit-test", "integration-test"})
public class ScopeRepositoryTest {

@Autowired
private ScopeRepository scopeRepository;
private Scope scope1;

@Before
public void setup() {
    scopeRepository.deleteAll();
}
}_
```

When we execute the test case test case fails on start up with below error:

`Thread-3] o.s.b.a.mongo.embedded.EmbeddedMongo : 2020-08-26T14:00:21.257+0530 I ACCESS [conn2] SCRAM-SHA-1 authentication failed for admin on admin from client 127.0.0.1:56763 ; UserNotFound: Could not find user admin@admin. admin/admin are username/password of local db name as admin`

With older version of spring boot 2.2.5/7 and related mongodb packages, it works fine.

Comment: Can any one please provide some information?

Answer (score 3):

Embedded mongo starts in auth mode if it finds the credentials being used like mine had the credentials in application yml in default, I used another test spring profile and added @ActiveProfiles("test") to my test class

```html
spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: default
  data:
    mongodb:
      database: test_db
      username: adminuser
      password: adminpwd
      host: localhost
      port: 27012
---
spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: test
```